# What advanced math topics are recommended for computer science?

Tags: mathematical-programming

I am enrolled in a computer science degree at the moment. I have looked around trying to find answers, but people tend to ask 'what is the minimum math needed for computer science' as opposed to what is recommended. I am very interested in theoretical computer science topics. My interests sort of jump around but right now I have a distinct interest in cryptography.

I have always loved math. In high school I did advanced math units - equivalent to calc 1 & 2, as well as discrete math. Right now I am doing a linear algebra unit and a calc 3 unit (as well as my cs units). Next semester I will be doing a unit on number theory. But what else? What other units would actually help with computer science? For example, I can't imagine learning about differential equations would be applicable to computer science.

Comment: I'd say you can find applications for any kind of math in computer science really. But taking math will never hurt you, no matter what flavor it comes in. It will help you think in the right way. Take all the possible math you can.

Comment: I'm asking because I don't want to take math units that I will never actually use. I would rather take more cs units.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate but I can't find anything. Anyone?

Comment: This question is cross-posted on [Academia SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/43858/546).

Comment: What mathematics is directly relevant depends on what computer science you want to study. CS is a very broad field.

Comment: Differential equations are used in some areas, for example in random graph theory. See for example this survey: http://users.monash.edu.au/~nwormald/papers/de.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do theoretical computer science, more math the better. Ultimately, learning math is not so much about learning specific topics, though that is of course important, it is also about gaining mathematical maturity, which means being able to think mathematically, being able to formalise and prove things, being able to abstract away inessential details and capture the essence of a problem. Of course, actually knowing lots of useful theorems is important too.

For crypto you'll need (at least) algebra (group theory etc), number theory, and discrete mathematics. Some logic wouldn't hurt either.

Linear algebra will help with machine learning and computer graphics.

Logic, topology and category theory will help for many Theory B topics (programming language semantics etc).

The list goes on ...